# Is there any large diffeomorphisms of $S^{n}\times S^1 $like Torus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

We know that a Torus is mapped onto itself in a special discontinuous transformation given by $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Thinking of torus as $S^{1}\times S^{1}$ and thus as a lattice, we can easily show the above claim by mapping the fundamental region back to itself.

But now I am looking for the generalization of such a thing in $S^{n} \times S^1$ where $n > 1$. Is there any literature on such a manifold ? Or is a there a way to think of the above manifold as a lattice and thus find the transformations on the fundamental region ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by either "discontinuous" or "large" here. (Also, do you mean $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?) Do you mean not isotopic to the identity?

Comment: Discontinuous in the sense, it can't be deformed continuously. I think the definition of large diffeomorphism is that you can't achieve them by infinitesimal transformations, like $x \rightarrow -x$ can't be achieved by continuos transformations.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you're asking what the so-called "Mapping class group" of these manifolds are. This is the group of diffeomorphisms, modulo the subgroups of diffeomorphisms isotopic to the identity (those that can be "continuously deformed" into the identity diffeomorphism).

The mapping class group of $S^1$ is $\Bbb Z/2$ (the nontrivial element is reflection). The mapping class group of $S^1 \times S^2$ is $(\Bbb Z/2)^3$ (the first term is generated by the reflection on $S^1$, the second reflection on $S^2$, and the third the diffeomorphism $(\theta,x) \mapsto (\theta, \text{rot}_{\theta} x)$.)

There are calculations of the (smooth, continuous, PL) mapping class groups of the tori $(S^1)^n$ by experts in surgery theory. It is possible the same group of people have calculations of $S^1 \times S^n$ for $n>3$; I do not know these results. (I promise you nobody knows the smooth mapping class group of $S^1 \times S^3$.)

But certainly you can verify they all contain a copy of $(\Bbb Z/2)^2$ acting in the same way as the thing before. To get the last term, you would need to understand $\pi_1 \text{Diff}(S^n)$; there has certainly been work on this in high dimensions.